# Input text to tapped UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I have looked for an answer to this issue, but I have not found anything that relates to my specific issue very well. I have multiple UILabels, and I am trying to change the text according to which UIButton is pressed (similar to the phone feature on an iphone). I have this method working for a single, known UILabel. However, I am now trying to write to a label when multiple labels are present. I want to identify which label to write text to by tapping the label, but I cannot get the code working... My methods are below:

```
// init method
answerFieldC.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
touch = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(inputAnswer:)];
[touch setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[answerFieldC addGestureRecognizer:touch];

-(IBAction)inputAnswer:(id)sender {
    strC = [answerFieldC text];
    currentLabel = touch.view;

    if (currentLabel==answerFieldC) {
        [strC stringByAppendingString:[sender currentTitle]];
        [answerFieldC setText:strC];
    }
}
```

The other labels are operating under the same inputAnswer and init code. `answerFieldC` is the label and `strC` is the string that stores the text of the label.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What about using .tag?

Comment: I tried that... It still didn't work :/

Comment: `[strC stringByAppendingString:[sender currentTitle]]` won't do anything unless you assign the result of that expression to a variable. Presumably you meant `strC = [strC stringByAppendingString:[sender currentTitle]];`

Comment: i edited your answer to include the inputAnswer method declaration.. am i correct?

Comment: esker I tried the variable assignment, but it did not change the outcome. Also, abbood, I have a method declaration in the actual code, and "touch" is a global instance variable, so I do not think I need to pass it as an argument. Thank you for your help so far everyone. If you have other ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Are you reusing the same "touch" instance var for all of the labels?  If so, that's the problem.  Can you post code for answerFieldA or B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach ought to work.  Something is wrong with a detail.  I suspect that you forgot to setup the labels to receive touches (they don't by default).  It ought to work as simply as this...

```
// MyViewController.m

@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelA;   // presumably these are painted in IB
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelB;

// notice no gesture recognizer ivars here

// @implementation ...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapA = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [self.labelA addGestureRecognizer:tapA];

    // You can set this in IB, but it must be set somewhere
    self.labelA.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapB = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [self.labelB addGestureRecognizer:tapB];
    self.labelB.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Notice two things: (1) we set userInteractionEnabled = YES on the labels, and (2) there are two gesture recognizers, one to do a job for each label.  We don't need ivars for them.  They are where they need to be; attached to subviews.  (you can always get them by saying `self.labelA.gestureRecognizers`, but I rarely find the need to in practice)

```
- (void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)gr.view;
    NSLog(@"the label tapped is %@", label.text);
}
```

Notice the form of this method matches @abbood's suggestion.  The first param is the gr, and can be accessed this way, without use of an ivar.  This runs fine in my Xcode.

Comment: It now works very well. I think I was trying to combine too many tasks in one method, and it was throwing off my program logic. Thanks! And thank you to abbood and everyone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use UIButton and make them look like labels?

```
UIButton whateverYouCallYourButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[whateverYouCallYourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(itemClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:whateverYouCallYourButton];
```

Then make itemClicked like this...

```
- (void)itemClicked: (id)sender {
// stuff you want to do here
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid using buttons, but if I cannot get the labels working, I will try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you declare the method that's called when your label is tapped (ie inputAnswer).. it should be like so:

```
-(void)inputAnswer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    strC = [answerFieldC text];
    // the gesture object tells you what you view you tapped
    currentLabel = gesture.view;

    if (currentLabel==answerFieldC) {
        [strC stringByAppendingString:[sender currentTitle]];
        [answerFieldC setText:strC];
    }
}
```